# Maintain Select state in UI5 Treetable on Toggle

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAP UI5 TreeTable with one RootNode and 5 Child Nodes. When I click on one of the child nodes, it gets highlighted to Blue. But, when I try to collapse and expand the treeTable, the selection made earlier is lost now. "Treetable" has "attachToggleOpenState" event, but it doesn't help in retaining the selection.

Please help in how to maintain the selection state while toggling.

Comment: I don't think the API supports that at the moment. You can use `getSelectedIndex` (when collapsing) and `setSelectedIndex` (when expanding) in your event handler, but this will only work in the most simple cases (collapsing and immediately expanding).

Comment: @Marc Thanks Marc. Will try it out.